# 3.5" SATAs in an HP DL580 G4

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, sata

I've been tasked to marry a bunch of 3.5" SATA drives with an HP Proliant DL580 G4 server. Trouble is, this server only takes Small Form Factor harddisks.

How can I make this happen in the most simple way?

I was thinking of an external disk enclosure. Maybe a Storageworks. (We have a couple of spare Fiber Channel cards and a P400 which might come in handy.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internal use of 3.5" disks is not going to be possible on the [HP ProLiant DL580 G4](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12473_na/12473_na.html) system.

Given than that the system is an older generation ProLiant, the best matching solution (and path of least resistance) is to obtain a period-correct external enclosure for the system. In this case, that would be an [HP StorageWorks MSA60 12-bay enclosure](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12627_div/12627_div.HTML). Pair that with a [Smart Array P800 RAID controller](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12616_na/12616_na.html) and you'll have a workable solution. You will need 3.5" drive caddies if you don't already have them (HP part #373211-002)

The MSA60 and P800 can be found cheaply on eBay.

---

I'm decommissioning a DL580 G4 as I write this. It may not be worth investing any money in that hardware. It's been eclipsed by *two* model revisions.

A cleaner solution, if you simply need the large form-factor drive bays, would be to find a [ProLiant DL180 G6](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13248_na/13248_na.HTML) unit. It can accommodate 14 LFF disks and would be sub $3000US.