# Is it possible to convert an HP MSA20 from U320 to SAS?

Tags: hp, hp-smart-array, hp-modular-smart-array

Is it possible to replace the U320 controller(s) from an MSA20 with SAS/SATA controller(s) in order to attach the MSA20 to a SAS host adapter, like a P800 or P400 for example?

Comment: MSA60s are dirt cheap on eBay - probably your best bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It's not possible.

The [**HP StorageWorks MSA20**](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/11942_div/11942_div.html) is an Ultra 320 parallel SCSI-*only* device for its external interface. It's a SATA backplane... But remember, it's first-generation SATA; 1.5Gbps. Terrible.

If you want something compatible, you'll need an MSA50, MSA60, MSA70, D2600 or D2700... You get the idea. Something more modern.

Also see the advice given on your previous question:
[3.5" SATAs in an HP DL580 G4](https://serverfault.com/questions/419011/3-5-satas-in-an-hp-dl580-g4)